# Is it possible the GC called in the destructor of a class implemented IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

-----------Edit1----------

Sorry for my poor english, seems the original question can't make sense for many people, so I greatly simplified the question just to two sentence:

In msdn code sample of  [IDisposable pattern in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx), Putting releasing un-managed resource code in destructor was for the purpose of when user forgot to call the `Dispose()` to release the resource, the GC still can help to release at least un-managed resource, but, when a class used some un-managed resources, it must registered (implicitly or explicitly) current instance (or fields) to GC handle table and then would never be GCed, so how the code in destructor get executed in this situation?

-----------End Edit1-------

We know the famous `IDisposable` pattern which could see lots in web like: [IDisposable pattern in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)

In samples, as I understood, the purpose of destructor works for the case: If user forgot explicitly call `Dispose()`, then **GC will help** and release un-managed resources.

But I just wondering that destructor in any case could get called by GC **without** user code explicitly call `Dispose()` first?

The guess was based on reason of Implementing `IDisposable` and had an explicit destructor:

This class used some un-managed resources. No matter by P/Invoke or managed API (BCL), As I know, both way need add a **GC handle entry** to GC handle table which **avoid** GCed, thus the destructor would never be called by GC.

So we should never expect luck on resources automatically release? and why put that in sample code?

Comment: The garbage collector can dispose of objects that are no longer referenced by other code loaded in memory, so yes, the GC can clean up without you explicitly telling it too.  This is how it is supposed to prevent memory leaks within .NET.

Comment: Having trouble understanding the question. Can you simplify?

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of questions here. Let's try to answer all of them.

> In the MSDN code sample of the `IDisposable` pattern code to release unmanaged resources is put in the destructor. This ensure that when a user forgots to call `Dispose()` to release the resource, the GC still releases the unmanaged resources.

Correct.

> But when a class uses some unmanaged resources, it must have registered the current instance to GC handle table and then would never be GCed.

I don't understand this sentence. What is the "GC handle table" that you speak of?

Can you show some sample code that demonstrates your scenario?

> How does the code in destructor get executed in this situation?

Briefly the GC works like this. The GC knows the "roots"; these are the references that are definitely alive. The GC first marks all the objects as dead. Then it marks the roots as alive. Then it marks everything the roots refer to as alive, and then every that *they* refer to as alive, and so on.  That is *everything reachable from a root is alive*.  Then the GC kills everything that is still marked as dead.

Now, if a dead object is finalizable -- if it has a destructor that has not run yet -- then the GC does NOT kill the object. The object is put on a list of objects to be finalized, and this list is a root, so the object is alive again.  Later on, another thread runs the destructors of every object on the finalization queue and removes them from the queue, and marks them as no longer requiring finalization.

The next time the GC runs, if the object is still dead then it is collected and the finalizer is not run again.

> Can the destructor get called by the GC without user code explicitly call `Dispose()` first?

Yes. That's the whole point of the destructor.

Comment: The _GC handle table_ may not the correct term. Let's make it short: managed code call unmanaged API, it always(?) need add itself to avoid get GCed via `GCHandle.Alloc(object)`, obviously this registration made the destructor would never be called, so in this situation (and I feels this is the most situation), the expected 'GC help release unmanaged resource' would never work. Then why put the sample code in msdn which actually would not running in most time?

Comment: @shawn if you need the object to stay alive then why not use GC.keepalive?

Answer (score 2):

GC uses a mechanism called finalization to handle such classes that implement `IDisposable`.

If you properly implement the class, then when `Dispose` was not called, GC will take care of the object when it is out of scope, and the finalizer will be called by GC. The finalizer is called implicitly, and at a unpredictable time.

More technical details can be found from books such as CLR via C#, or articles such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx

Comment: It's called a destructor in C#; read the specification if you don't believe me. Whether you call it a destructor (the correct term in C#) or a finalizer (the correct term in IL), it doesn't matter; they are the same thing in C#, and people will understand you.